# AngularJS - Using a drectory with template code for a search function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, angularjs-directive

Once again I am having trouble with some code in AngularJS.

This time it's mainly due to directories because it'd worked without it before.

In my opinion the main issue is related to the functions `do_sort()` and `do_show()` from the `directives.js` template code which never actually get called.

Although there is to mention, that the link part of the template code gets rendered as desired (see printscreen).[image]

Any smart guesses what I am missing?

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TodoApp">
<head>
    <!-- Core AngularJS -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom AngularJS files -->
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/services.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/directives.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="Content/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Content/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.icon-large.css" />

    <title>Amazing Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### List.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th sorted="Todo">Todo</th>
        <th sorted="Priority">Priority</th>
        <th sorted="DueDate">Due</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
            <td>{{item.Todo}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Priority}}</td>
            <td>{{item.DueDate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### controllers.js

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $location, todoApiService) {

    $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.todos = todoApiService.getMyTodos().query({ sort: $scope.sort_order, desc: $scope.is_desc });
    };

    $scope.sort = function(col) {
        if ($scope.sort_order === col) {
            $scope.is_desc = !$scope.is_desc;
            $scope.search();
        } else {
            $scope.sort_order = col;
            $scope.is_desc = false;
            $scope.search();
        }
    };

    $scope.sort_order = "Priority";
        $scope.is_desc = false;

        $scope.search();

    });
```

### directives.js

```
angular.module('TodoApp.directives', []).
    directive('sorted', function () {
        return {
            scope: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: '<a ng-click="do_sort()" ng-transclude></a>' +
                '<span ng-show="do_show(true)">></span>' +
                '<span ng-show="do_show(false)"><</span>',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                $scope.sort_order = $attrs.sorted;

                $scope.doSort = function () {
                    $scope.sort($scope.sort_order);
                };

                $scope.doShow = function (asc) {
                    return asc != $scope.is_desc && col == $scope.sort_order;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Either answer your own question, or delete it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renamed the two functions `doSort()` and `doShow()` to its proper name.

It's working now.

### directives.js

```
angular.module('TodoApp.directives', []).
    directive('sorted', function () {
        return {
            scope: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: '<a ng-click="do_sort()" ng-transclude></a>' +
                '<span ng-show="do_show(true)">></span>' +
                '<span ng-show="do_show(false)"><</span>',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                $scope.sort_order = $attrs.sorted;

                $scope.do_sort = function () {
                    $scope.sort($scope.sort_order);
                };

                $scope.do_show = function (asc) {
                    return asc != $scope.is_desc && col == $scope.sort_order;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```